# Adjust screen resolution scaling in Lumina desktop of TrueOS

Tags: resolution, trueos, lumina

Using [TrueOS](https://www.trueos.org) dated 2016-09-20 with [Lumina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-BSD#Lumina) desktop.

**How do we adjust the scaling** of the screen resolution?

I cannot find any kind of [pixel-density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) settings in any of the control panels. I see no info in the [TrueOS Handbook for Lumina configuration](https://www.trueos.org/handbook/luminaconfig.html).

Using TrueOS in a virtual machine ([Parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac) 12.0.2) on a MacBook Pro with a [Retina display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display). The VM is set to have resolution scaling enabled, yet every thing visible in the Lumina desktop is teeny-tiny.